# require_once is not loading file in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am running a Cron Job which requires me to load a file from one directory above my PHP script. Here is my file structure:

```
folder
--subfolder
  --my-script.php
  --header.php
--wp-load.php
--wp-config.php
```

I want to run `my-script.php` while loading the files `file-a.php`, `load-it.php` and `file-b.php`.

I was using the following code to load respective files:

```
require_once("header.php");


require_once("../wp-load.php");
require_once("../wp-config.php");
```

When I run the script in browser after uploading on the server or run it locally, the file paths are located correctly. However, when I run it as a Cron Job, only the `header.php` is loaded.

How can I correctly load the other files so that they run properly as a Cron Job?

Update: I have tried using:

```
require_once(__DIR__."/wp-load.php");
```

as well as

```
require_once(__DIR__."../wp-load.php");
```

They both don't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `require_once(__DIR__."/../wp-load.php");` (with the extra `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cron you'd need to refer to the full path to get it working correctly.

This will get you wp-load if it is one directory above the current file:

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../wp-load.php' );
```